# tar: Directory: Cannot rmdir: Directory not empty

Tags: linux, tar

I'm trying to understand what's the proper way of using `tar`. I have a directory called `main` and in the `sub` directory it contains some files and directories I want to exclude. All others I want to remove. The command I use:

```
tar --remove-files --exclude main/sub/.runtime --exclude main/sub/.startTime --exclude main/sub/subsubdir -zcvf main.tar.gz main
```

But I get:

```
tar: main/sub: Cannot rmdir: Directory not empty
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Now of course it the `main/sub` directory is not empty (because of the excluded files/directory). What's the proper way to resolve it without redirecting output to `/dev/null` or some other way? I want to still get errors but just not that one.

Answer (score 0):

How about first:

```
cd main
```

and then

```
tar --remove-files --exclude sub/.runtime --exclude sub/.startTime --exclude sub/subsubdir -zcvf main.tar.gz *
```

?

That should prevent the subdirectory errors,
also if you are using it in a script or with an alias:

```
( cd main;tar --remove-files --exclude sub/.runtime --exclude sub/.startTime --exclude sub/subsubdir -zcvf main.tar.gz * )
```

The ( prevents it from doing anything to the parent shell, so you stay in your directory

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. Prints: `tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug for `--remove-files` option.

Instead of excluding files, you can include files :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s dotglob extglob nullglob
tar -zcvf main.tar.gz main/!(sub) main/sub/!(*@(.runtime|.startTime|subsubdir))
```

Add `--remove-files` once you are satisfied with result.